# How to open a folder in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, directory

I'm looking for a way to open a folder in HTML5, like the `<input: file>` tag but for a folder, I've tried PHP, and s
SQL, but nothing seems to work.
Haxer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="folder">
    <audio src=music></audio>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ...and do what with it? What do you want to achieve with the folder?

Comment: Your questions is unclear. Give your full code so that we can understand what you tried and where was the wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to make a music player with a music path.bit like https://brastin3.itch.io/minimal-music-player but with html

Comment: You would need to have a  local server atleast, which takes the files and gives it to the website for it to play. I don't recommend using just the browser's filesystem API to open a folder and play, since this whole process is too over complicated and is not fully stable yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these attributes -

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory multiple />
```